# bash moving files to subdirectories according to their name

Tags: bash

I have files that are named like this:

```
A-1230.pdf
A-2450.pdf
A-6780.pdf

B-1230.pdf
B-2450.pdf
B-6780.pdf
```

... and a directory-structure like this:

```
A
- 000
- 001
-...
- 999

B
- 000
- 001
-...
- 999
```

No I want to move the files to their corresponding subdirectories. Means

```
A-1230.pdf goes into A -> 123
B-2450.pdf goes into B -> 245
```

And so on.

I tried the following with bash:

```
mv +([A-Z]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]*.pdf) $1/$2$3$4
```

But that's not working. How do I use backreferences and capturing groups in bash correctly?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you want a question that tells you how to do this with regular expressions, or just an answer that tells you how to do it *at all*? Note that `+([A-Z]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]*.pdf)` is an extglob, not a regex, and extglobs don't *have* capture groups.

Comment: This is more a ZSH thing (see `zmv`)

Comment: `$1` refers to the arguments your script/function/etc was called with; it's not relevant to any kind of shell-builtin regex capabilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex support in bash is used with `[[ $string =~ $regex ]]`, and places capture groups in the array `BASH_REMATCH`.

```
for file in ?-*.pdf; do
  [[ $file =~ ([[:alpha:]])-([[:digit:]]{3}).* ]] || continue
  mkdir -p -- "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}/${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" || continue 
  mv -- "$file" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}/${BASH_REMATCH[2]}/"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are attempting to achieve is what is called back-referencing. Unfortunately, there is no such concept for globular expressions. Expressions such as:

```
mv (*).pdf $1/
cp ([0-9])-(*).txt $2-$1.text
```

are simply not possible in any shell (bash, zsh, ksh, csh).

Workarounds exist by looping over every file and post process it a bit:

```
for file in [A-Z]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]*.pdf; do
   dir="${file:0:5}"; dir="${dir/-/\/}"
   mkdir -p "$dir"
   mv "$file" "$dir"
done
```

or a bit more intelligently as is done by [Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51597227/8344060)

ZSH developed, for tasks like this, a set of separate tools (`zcp`, `zmv` and `zln`) which allow back referencing. So your task could be performed as:

```
zmv -n '([A-Z])-([0-9][0-9][0-9])[0-9].pdf' '$1/$2/'
```

The `-n` flag shows what it will do but not actually perform the action as it acts as a dry-run. remove the flag to perform the actual moves.

**note:** ZSH does not have back-referencing for globular expressions. Notice the single quotes used in the `zmv` example above. They prohibit globbing. The FROM and DEST part are arguments past to those tools. The tools are also not found in any `$PATH` as they are part of the zsh system. This in contrast to `cp`, `mv` and `ln` which are actual binaries.